# Table or view not found in synapse

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, dataverse, azure-synapse-analytics

Pipeline and Dataflow is working fine in dev env with same configuration IR. But when its deployed to Test env, pipeline is getting failed with below errors. I am trying to read a table from dataverse.

Pipeline:
[image]

Dataflow:

[image]

{"message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'contactRaw': Table or view not found: **blobcontainername**.contact;\n'UnresolvedRelation [**blobcontainername**, contact], [], false\n. Details:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: **blobcontainername**.contact;\n'UnresolvedRelation [**blobcontainername**, contact], [], false\n\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:113)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:184)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:90)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:155)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:178)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst","failureType":"UserError","target":"rawToCuratedDF","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}

Comment: Can you add your pipeline flow and dataflow image for better understanding?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Updated the post as you asked.